# Sonin inversion formula, equivalence of two solutions of an integral equation

Tags: real-analysis, integral-transforms, singular-integral-equations

Let me first specify the problem I am facing, and then below explain where it arises. Given a function $f(x)$ on the interval $0<x<1$ and a real number $s\in(-1,1)$ I consider the integral transforms
$$A_{f,s}(x)=x^{s_-}\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^1 dt\,\frac{(t-x)^{s_+}}{ t^{s}}\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t dy\, y^{s_+}(t-y)^{s_-}f(y),$$
$$B_{f,s}(x)=-x^{s_+}\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^1 dt\,\frac{(t-x)^{s_-}}{ t^{s}}\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t dy\, y^{s_-}(t-y)^{s_+}f(y),$$
with $s_\pm=(s\pm 1)/2$. I wish to prove that these two transforms are equivalent for $0<x<1$, in the sense that they differ by an $x$-independent multiple of the function
$$Z_s(x)=x^{s_-}(1-x)^{s_-}.$$

I checked this by explicit calculation for a polynomial $f(y)=y^p$, when I find
$$A_{f,s}(x)-B_{f,s}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{p+1}\pi\Gamma(3/2+s/2)}{\cos(\pi s/2)\Gamma(p+s+1)\Gamma(1/2-p-s/2)} Z_s(x).$$

**Q:** Can this equivalence be shown more generally, for smooth $f(y)$?

---

*Motivation:* According to the Sonin inversion formula, the integral equation ($\cal P$ denotes the principal value)
$${\cal P}\int_0^1 dy\,g(y)\frac{\text{sign}(x-y)}{|x-y|^{s+1}}=f(x),\;\;
0<x<1,$$
has for $-1<s<1$ the two special solutions $c_sA_{f,s}(x)$ and $c_sB_{f,s}(x)$ [with $c_s=-\frac{\Gamma(s+1)\sin\pi s_+}{\pi s_+\Gamma(s_+)^2}$, see appendix B of [arXiv:cond-mat/0012513](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0012513)]. The homogenous integral equation (with zero on the right-hand-side) has the solution $Z_s(x)$. So I wish to verify that the general solution of the integral equation can be written either as $g(x)=c_sA_{f,s}(x)+CZ_s(x)$ or as $g(x)=c_sB_{f,s}(x)+CZ_s(x)$, for some $x$-independent coefficient $C$.

Comment: What is known about $f$?

Comment: $f\in L^1$ on $[0,1]$ should be sufficient.

Comment: If $p=(1-s)/2$ and $f(x)=x^p$ for $x\in(0,1)$, then $f\in L^1(0,1)$ and $f$ is smooth on $(0,1)$, and yet, according to your post, your desired statement fails to hold.

Comment: thank you for your comment; the formula I gave was for integer ; for $p=(1-s)/2\in(0,1)$ I find numerically that $$A_{f,s}(x)-B_{f,s}(x)=-Z_s(x),$$ so the equivalence statement still holds.

Comment: The expression should be analytic in $p$. So, I don't see how it can be finite for $p=(1-s) /2$.

Comment: The correct expression for real $p\in (0,1)$ is
$$
\frac{A_{f,s}(x)-B_{f,s}(x)}{Z_s(x)} =
\frac{-\pi\,\Gamma\big(\frac {s+3} 2 \big)}
{\cos\big[\pi\big(\frac s 2+ p\big)\big]\,\Gamma\big(p+s+1\big)\,\Gamma\big(\frac {1-s} 2-p\big)} 
\stackrel{p\to\frac{1-s}{2}}{=}-1,
$$
so @Carlo's statement holds. Furthermore, it holds for all $f(x)$ that can be expanded into a power series around $x=0$, as the integral equations are linear.